# Does EF have ordered collections? The equivalent of list in the NHibernate Bag Vs Set Vs List world

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4

Does the Entity Framework 4 have ordered collections?

For example my Order has a property that is a collection of OrderItems, but the order is important and I would rather not sort them before I access them.

See Nhibernate for an example:
[List vs Set vs Bag in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916350/set-bag-and-list-set-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't. You can force an order in a couple of ways however :

This answer explains one [EF4 LINQ Ordering Parent and all child collections with Eager Loading (.Include())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156949/ef4-linq-ordering-parent-and-all-child-collections-with-eager-loading-include) (kind of)

More simply, if you are querying a single order, you can do so with the orderlines ordered in a specifc way:

```
var thing = _repo.GetOrder(id)
 .Select(item => 
    new { item, ord = item.orderlines.OrderBy(o => o.orderbythis) }
    ).FirstOrDefault().item;
```

Comment: keep in mind this will return an "item" without the "ord" - you havent't assigned the "ord" anonymous property back into the projected type.

Comment: Yes I know. However item.orderlines IS ordered in the specified manner. I guess there is a danger this may break in future releases, but it does work! If anyone can explain why this works I'd love to know!