# OrderBy on children in a LINQ Query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EF4 LINQ Ordering Parent and all child collections with Eager Loading (.Include())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156949/ef4-linq-ordering-parent-and-all-child-collections-with-eager-loading-include)

Hello everybody

I have a *user* entity who contains a one to many relationship with a *role* entity

So with this linq expression :

```
from user in USER_TABLE.Include("USERROLE_TABLE")
order by user.Name
select user
```

I can get users with related roles as a child.
My problem is that i want to get roles of each user ordered alphabetically.
How can i do that ? I googled a lot and don't find anything

Thank's by advance !

Comment: What's wrong if you replacing your select with `select user.Role`?

Answer (score 1):

So, just to clarify, you have a table which includes essentially:

```
Name : Role
--------------
Bob : leader
Jane : scribe
Bob : technician
Bob : programmer
Jane : entity
Bob : adept
```

and you want to end up with:

```
Bob : adept
Bob : leader
Bob : programmer
Bob : technician
Jane : entity
Jane : scribe
```

If that's the case, then you're looking at an "orderby, thenby", which in LINQ I believe is indicated by a comma in that part of the LINQ statement:

```
orderby user.Name, user.Role
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no i have two tables, is it working for me ?

Comment: But after including, you've essentially got one collection, which you can order however you like.  Is the output that I've proposed what you're intending to end up with - that you're hoping to order by one criteria (name), with results within that criteria ordered by a subsequent criteria (role)?  Or do you want to end up with a scenario where you have a collection of (users) with no duplications, in which each user has a primary criteria (roles) field which contains a list of secondary criteria (role), containing none to many roles?