# How can i load collection with include

Tags: linq, entity-framework, include

How can I load collection with include, I have tried these:

1. `Type.Where(t => t.Entity.Where(e => e.Parent == false).Count() > 0).Include(e => e.Entity)`

   But the filter is not supported here (Entities recovered not fulfill a condition).
2. With LinQ To Entities :

   ```
   var v = from type in ObjectContext.Type
           from entity in Type.Entities
           where entity.Parent == false
           select type;
   ```

But type do not contains it's associated `Entities`.

I can't write `select new Type { type.Code, type.Entities }` and I can't use anonymous type as it's not adapted for my repository layer.

Have you any ideas on how I can get a list of `Type` objects with its property `Entities` satisfying a condition?

**Update**

Thank you for your response

I think it's not a good idea to use the CTP , no ?

I am sorry, I did not explain my object model, I have :

```
class Type {
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public IList<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
  ...
}

class Entity {
  public string Code { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

And I want to use your second filtering proposal : Filter both entity sets

Do you have any suggestions without using the CTP ?

Thanks
Rad

Comment: are you trying to include all related entities or do you want to apply filters as well when including?

Comment: Hi Ivanov, I want apply filters as well when including

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Please_ simply edit your question (click the edit link) to add additional information, or use comments to reply to answers that you receive. The answer field is reserved strictly for answers.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156949/ef4-linq-ordering-parent-and-all-child-collections-with-eager-loading-include/4157221#4157221 . Using this `CreateSourceQuery` as proposed there, it requires 2 roundtrips to the DB, but the CTP solution requires 2 trips as well. It seems to be impossible to apply filters to navigation properties when you are using `Include` to have only one trip to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

as you stated you want to apply filters to the related entities, best to look at the new CTP5 of the EF4 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx
Look under "Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities"