# What is a 'Bag' and a 'Set' in nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

Using Fluent NHibernate, I come across the mapping `AsBag()` and `AsSet()` for `HasMany` and `HasManyToMany` relationships. I've done some searches, and I'm just not finding anything. Can anyone explain to me what these mean, and what the significance is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set/bag and list/set in nhibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916350/set-bag-and-list-set-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2390190) succinctly explains the differences.

In summary, they are both unordered collections:

- **Set** => Item may not occur more than once
- **Bag** => Items may occur more than once

Answer (score 7):

Check out this SO article:  [List vs Set vs Bag in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916350/set-bag-and-list-set-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the mathematical concepts Set / Multiset (Bag) and see if they can push you into the right direction.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset