# NHibernate casting issue (suspected cause is incorrect mapping)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, mapping

I'm having trouble mapping my M:1 relationship between Petition and PetitionSignature in NHibernate.  This is a type of relationship I've mapped before, but I just can't get it working right now.

The method I am trying to call in my provider is designed to return a collection of PetitionSignatures based on the Petition object that was passed in:

```
public IList<PetitionSignature> GetByPetition(Petition p)
{
    IList<PetitionSignature> Signatures = (IList<PetitionSignature>)_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PetitionSignature))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Petition", p))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id")).List();
    return Signatures.OrderBy(sig => sig.Date).ToList();
}
```

My Petition class is defined as:

```
public class Petition : IPetition
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string Slug { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PetitionSignature> Signatures { get; set; }
}
```

My PetitionSignature class is defined as:

```
public class PetitionSignature : IPetitionSignature
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Petition Petition { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual bool OkToEmail { get; set; }

}
```

My Petition mapping document is:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<property name="Title" column="Title"></property>
<property name="Text" column="Text"></property>
<property name="Date" column="Date"></property>
<property name="Slug" column="Slug"></property>

<bag name="Signatures" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="Id"/>
  <one-to-many class="PetitionSignature"/>
</bag>
```

And my PetitionSignature mapping document is as follows:

```
<property name="Name" column="Name"></property>
<property name="EmailAddress" column="EmailAddress"></property>
<property name="Date" column="Date"></property>
<property name="OkToEmail" column="OkToEmail"></property>
<property name="PhoneNumber" column="PhoneNumber"></property>
<property name="StreetAddress" column="StreetAddress"></property>

  <many-to-one name="Petition" class="Petition" column="Petition" cascade="all" />
```

These are the columns of my Petition table:
[image: Petition Table]

And these are the columns of my PetitionSignature table:
[image: PetitionSignature Table]

So here's what happens.  I run my integration test in debug mode and test this out.  I hydrate my Petition object with no trouble, and pass it to this method in the PetitionSignatureProvider class.  That's when this happens:
[image: Exception Time!]

Of course, this conversion can be made.  Creating another method in the provider that accepts a PetitionId, the conversion is made fine.  This leads me to believe the problem is with my mapping, shown above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of a criteria query is **not** a generic list, it returns an object that implements `IList`, so you can't just cast it to a generic list. You can however convert it to a generic list, by using the extension methods on `IEnumerable`. The following code should work:

```
public IList<PetitionSignature> GetByPetition(Petition p)
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PetitionSignature))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Petition", p))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
        .List()
        .Cast<PetitionSignature>()
        .OrderBy(sig => sig.Date)
        .ToList();
}
```

But you already have a `Petition` object. If this object is fetched via NHibernate by the same session, then you can just write:

```
public IList<PetitionSignature> GetByPetition(Petition p)
{
    return p.Signatures.OrderBy(sig => sig.Date).ToList();
}
```

Or even better, you don't need a method at all. Just write

```
p.Signatures.OrderBy(sig => sig.Date)
```

whenever you need the signatures of a specific petition ordered by date. Besides this, I have a couple of suggestions regarding your code:

- There is a mistake in you mapping file. The `<key>` element in your bag should refer to the *foreign key field of the PetitionSignature table*. It should be: `<key column="Petition" />`
- If your NHibernate version is not too old, I would use the new `QueryOver` api, or `NHibernate.Linq`. These are both typesafe query APIs that use lambda expression instead of magic strings.
- I think you want to use a `<set>` instead of a `<bag>`. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916350/set-bag-and-list-set-in-nhibernate) for more information about sets and bags.

Comment: Thank you Elian.  You are right about the final code snippet, but it was the concept covered in your first codeblock that I was trying to rectify.  This makes perfect sense with the information you and Inerdia have provided.  +1

Answer (score 1):

`System.Collections.ArrayList` does *not* implement the generic interface `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, but the non-generic interface `System.Collections.IList`. These shouldn't be compatible unless C# does some magic I'm not aware of in this case.

If NHibernate has an API that returns generic collections, you should use that to retrieve results. Otherwise, you could use `IEnumerable.OfType()` or `IEnumerable.Cast()`.

If this works in a different method, it could be that NHibernate returns a generic collection when navigating an association that uses a generic type in the entity class, but returns a non-generic collection when using the ICriteria API to query for a list of entities. The documentation also implies that the newer QueryOver API also uses generics.

Comment: Thank you Inerdia, I appreciate your explanation of this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `.List<PetitionSignature>()` instead of `.List()` with Criteria. That will return the generic collection that you're expecting, without the need for casts.

Now, there **is** a mapping error which is preventing you from doing this in a much simpler way:

```
<bag name="Signatures" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="Petition"/> <!-- This is the FK -->
  <one-to-many class="PetitionSignature"/>
</bag>
```

With that, you can just use petition.Signatures, no need for a Criteria query.

Comment: That is what I initially had, and I edited my mapping file thinking that the problem was there, thus creating this problem.  I have since fixed that in my project, but thank you for pointing this out, +1