# What is the meaning of defining lazy='false' and bag in hbm maps of nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

If lazy='false' is for defining the one to many relationship. What is the purpose of bag. What makes them differ.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy is weather lazy loading is enabled for the given collection, if enabled (true) then it will only load the list only when it's accessed.

About the second question, bag is a collection type and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916350/list-vs-set-vs-bag-in-nhibernate) question for more information

Comment: What happens actually on setting lazy loading as false or true. Is there any problem or benefit in setting the those values

Comment: Setting lazy=true will not load related entities, which would reduce number of queries to the database and it's an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy have `bool` type. If you have set Lazy value is `false` then that property load data while class is used in operation or not. But when you set `true` that is load data while you can access this property.

So in my opinion you should set `true` for faster load data.